# What is the minimum internal temperature measured inside meat (not air temperature) for pork ribs to be safe?

Tags: pork, barbecue, ribs

I want to experiment to prepare the pork ribs in Weber Kettle charcoal grill on a minimum possible temperature. What is the minimum internal temperature measured inside the meat (not air temperature) for pork ribs to be safe? By safe I mean meat to be prepared so that it is safe to eat.

Comment: It's not a fixed temperature.  [It's a function of time + temperature](http://douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Table_5.1)

Comment: @Joe not sure whether we already have a duplicate Q/A, but if not, your link looks like a good basis for an answer. (hint, hint...)

Comment: @Stephie : if someone else has time to do it, great.  I'd use the 5mm numbers, but there are risks (as you'd want to know that you're in the coldest part, which might be closer to the bone for ribs)

Comment: @Joe It is very interesting table. Thank you. As I understand It shows temperature and time of water when making Sous Vide. It there any such kind of table that shows the safe  temperature and time inside the pork?

Comment: @rumtscho : 'recommended temperature' is not the same as 'minimum safe', because it's assumes you just contact that temperature, not that you hold it for an period of time.  You can pasteurize at lower temperatures

Comment: @vasili111 : and I usually get bitched at for answering questions in comments ... but as *cough* someone *cough* closed the question, I can't answer it normally.   If you know that the meat is a uniform temperature, and your thermometer is accurate, use the times for 5mm thick cuts.  If you want some additional safety margin (and I would for ribs due to to the bones), use the times for one of the thicker cuts ... maybe 10mm or 15mm.

Comment: The safe temp for pork is usually considered to be 145F to 165F, but if you cook ribs only to this temp they will be extremely tough and nearly inedible.  Ribs on the grill become tender only after a long slow cook, the collagen and connective tissue that makes them tough starts to break down at 165F and it's only when they get up to about 180-190F that they start to become tender.  An internal temp of 145-165 for pork would only be good for something like a tenderloin.